# Why does my blender file close a few seconds after opening it and how do I fix this?

Tags: blend-files, startup-file

When I open a blender file, my project is visible for a few seconds while I can't make any changes to it, and then it closes. Does anyone know how to fix this? This doesn't happen to all of my blender files by the way. I can also start a new project.

Comment: I use version 2.80

Comment: Try to start Blender in debug mode. If you're on Windows you can find a file called `blender_debug_log.cmd` in the folder where Blender is installed. Double click it and it will start Blender and create a log file reporting errors that occur. On Linux and macOS you will have to start it from a terminal with the `--debug` flag.

Comment: That went easier then expected. Thanks!

Comment: In case it wasn't clear, that doesn't fix the problem, it's just to find out what went wrong.

Answer (score 2):

This may be caused by any single object in your file. Try opening a new project, click **File -> Append**, and add the objects from your corrupt file chunk by chunk or piece by piece. This way you can narrow down, if or which single object causes Blender to crash.